# Android: Call Function on Appear

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an app that needs to do something every time it is brought up on screen. In my onCreate function, the app checks the user's settings and performs an action. In some cases, the user will need to change their settings in order to proceed. How do I make the app call the onCreate function again once the user returns to the app? Or better yet, what function is called when a view appears? Thank you!

**This is how I am navigating away from my app (via a button):**

```
if(!networkEnabled){

AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Network Location Required");
alertDialog.setMessage("Please enable your network location settings to use the app");
alertDialog.setButton("Open", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(dialogIntent);
}
});
alertDialog.show();
}
```

**And then I am using onStart like this:**

```
public void onStart(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onStart();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) of an Activity. If an Activity returns from the background the first callback which is fired is onRestart()->onStart()->onResume(). Probably you will execute your code in onStart(). The View will be visible after onStart() is called.

Edit:

Move your code into onResume() for this situation. One hint to better understand the lifecycle. Override `all callbacks of the lifecycle` like this and watch the Logcat:

```
public void onStart(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onStart();
    Log.w("myActivity","onStart is called");
}
```

Comment: thanks steve, do I need to call onPause() in order to be able to cause onStart? as of right now, if I if I navigate away from the app and come back, placing code in the onStart() callback doesn't fire

Comment: Don't call these callback yourself, the system knows what to do. It depends how you navigate away from the app. Do some Logging in the callbacks to see what happens. Try your code in onResume(). This callback always will be fired at this situation.

Comment: ok i will update my question with how I am navigating away. I will also post what I am putting in onStart()

Comment: hmmm feel like I'm getting closer, but its still not getting called - i added that log.w bit in as well and have been hitting the home button on the simulator and going back and forth. should i post my code?

Answer (score 0):

try  onRestart() method

```
@Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestart();
    }
```